# Accept button is not showing on Case List Views in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I have used select Filter By Owner: Name of the queue in filters.

[image]

Comment: Try to add some code that reproduces your issue

Comment: In Classic,  Accept button is showing but Lightning mode Accept button is not showing in Case object. Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have fixed impedimentds. In Case List View checked "new Case".

[image]